# Parse a large json response in chunks

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, chunks

Is there an accepted way to parse large json responses/files in Python?  To be clear I mean:

1. The data cannot be loaded into memory all at once.
2. You know nothing about the data other than that it is legal json.
3. The output format should be something that easily read in chunks(delimited by linebreak or YAMl for example.)

   This is the classic json problem, i've seen plenty of other posts on this, but they usually revolve around a specific json representation.  The key here is **you know nothing about the json**.

   I know how to build a parser to do this myself, but it really sucks to do.  I'm hoping there's already an accepted Python solution for this.

   Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple libraries that can do this. Most of them provide a SAX-like API (and are roughly equivalent to SAX-like JSON parsers for other languages), but [`iljson`](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) provides an API modeled on ElementTree's [`iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse), which is a lot nicer for Python.

Comment: @abarnert I've been messing with ijson. It seems to easily decode the json stream, but is there something in place that can be used to encode the produced event stream?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/). It provides event-based iterators and would be easier than writing your own from scratch.

Comment: I've been messing with ijson.  It seems to easily decode the json stream, but is there something in place that can be used to encode the produced event stream?

Comment: @JamieMarshall did you see the ObjectBuilder class? See the `items()` function source for how to use it. Or just use `items()` if it works for your purposes.